# RETURNing rows of data differently in same table if a specific column is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on a query:

```
SELECT D.PointPerson AS Person, R.[Name] AS Project, ISNULL(P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description], 'KanBan') AS Sprint, S.[Number] AS Story, T.[Name] AS Task,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 1 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Monday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 2 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Tuesday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 3 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Wednesday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 4 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Thursday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 5 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Friday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 6 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Saturday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 7 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Sunday,
   sum(D.[Hours]) AS Total
FROM DailyTaskHours D
INNER JOIN Task T ON D.TaskId = T.PK_Task 
INNER JOIN Story S ON T.StoryId = S.PK_Story 
LEFT JOIN Sprint P ON S.SprintId = P.PK_Sprint 
INNER JOIN Product R ON S.ProductId = R.PK_Product
GROUP BY D.PointPerson, R.[Name], P.[Name], P.[Description], S.[Number], T.[Name]
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNULL(P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description], 'KanBan') = 'KanBan'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END,
    Project ASC,
    Sprint ASC,
    Story ASC,
    Task ASC
```

As you can see, it brings together many tables columns together.

There are two tables with relationships to base table (DailyTaskHours):

[image]

Currently, my query retrieves all relationships to the right side of the above schema. In all of these cases, the column NonScrumStoryId in DailyTaskHours is NULL. As part of the same query, I would like to return all DailyTaskHours Entries including those where NonScrumSoryId is NULL. In this case there is no connection to the Task, Story, Sprint, or Product tables.

Here is what the table looks like currently:
[image]

So if the row was a NonScrumStory row, that is the column wasnt null in this row, it would populate the below table but Project, Sprint and Task would all be NULL. Story would be taken from NonScrumStory.IncidentNumber

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What if you changed your joins from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?  That will return records from `DailyTaskHours` even when the join field is null.

Comment: Good idea, this will return the fields I how. Now how do I make the Story column populate with NonScrumStory.IncidentNumber if and only if NonScrumStoryId is NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
INNER JOIN Task T ON D.TaskId = T.PK_Task
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN Task T ON D.TaskId = T.PK_Task
```

A LEFT join will not cut out rows from the table in the from clause when they don't match in a join clause.

Also, add a left join to NonScrumStoryId and then change your select to:

```
COALESCE(S.[Number], NonScrumStoryId.IncidentNumber)
```

COLLASCE checks if the first arguement is null, and if so returns the second arguement.  In this case, if the story is null it will return the IncidentNumber instead.

Answer (score 1):

do You mean something like this:

```
CASE
WHEN S.[Number] is null
THEN NonScrumStory.IncidentNumber
ELSE S.[Number]
END
as Story
```

? Replace Your defintion for the Story-field with this and try...